# How to get each object details in PowerShell ForEachObject loop

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to run PowerShell script in Parallel. I have this script below

```
foreach ($item in $temp)
{
        
        Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $item  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '.\InstallChromeinVM.ps1'
        
}
```

This above script will install chrome software one by one in each VM, now I would like to perform the same task in Parallel.

I know I can use the below foreach loop but how can I get the values of $item

```
$temp | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel 

{
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $item  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '.\InstallChromeinVM.ps1'
        
}
```

Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_` variable inside the script block to access the current iteration value. For example following code

```
1..10 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  Write-Host $_
}
```

will print numbers from 1 to 10 to the console.

Comment: This example may work for me but I am getting an error  Missing an argument for parameter 'Parallel'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' and try again.

Comment: Can you update your current code?

Comment: $desiredvmlist = Get-AzVM
$temp=$desiredvmlist.Name
$temp | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel
{
Write-Host "Running the Script in resource group $ResourceGroupName and in VM $PSItem"
}